# std::fstream read block of data from file and write data back to file until EOF

Tags: c++, fstream

I'm reading blocks of data from the file, but not all at once (ex. 3 bytes per read/write) and then write same 3 bytes back to file to the very same position inside a file, and then continue looping until there are no more blocks to read.

In other words I'm trying to rewrite the file by it's very contents.

However there is a problem that final output isn't the same as it was in the beginning.

Following sample code reads 3 bytes per iteration from a file "sample.txt", file contents are simple:

> 0123456789

after reading data and writing data back to file, the contents are:

> 012345345345

As you see data doesn't get rewritten correctly for some reason.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define BLOCK_SIZE 3

int main()
{
    // open file
    fstream file;
    file.open("sample.txt", ios::binary | ios::out | ios::in);

    // determine size and number of blocks to read
    file.seekg(0, ios::end);
    streampos size = file.tellg();
    int blocks = size / BLOCK_SIZE;

    cout << "size:\t" << size << endl;

    if (size % BLOCK_SIZE != 0)
    {
        ++blocks;
    }

    cout << "blocks:\t" << blocks << endl;

    // return to beginning
    file.seekg(ios::beg);

    // we will read data here
    unsigned char* data = new unsigned char[BLOCK_SIZE];
    streampos pos;

    // read blocks of data and write data back
    for (int i = 0; i < blocks; ++i)
    {
        pos = file.tellg();
        cout << "before read:\t" << pos << endl;

        // read block
        file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(data), BLOCK_SIZE);
        cout << "after read:\t" << file.tellg() << endl;

        // write same block back to same position
        file.seekp(pos);
        cout << "before write:\t" << file.tellg() << endl;
        file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(data), BLOCK_SIZE);
        cout << "after write:\t" << file.tellg() << endl;

        // reset buffer
        memset(data, 0, BLOCK_SIZE);
    }

    file.close();

    delete[] data;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Do you see what could be the reason for bad overwrite?

**EDIT:**
Sorry, I can't see how the linked duplicate answers my question, I'm simply unable to apply given answer to the code above.

Comment: This works for me. You do have a problem in that you do not handle the end-of-file condition very well.

Comment: How it works for you? Can you give the code that works?

Comment: I ran the exact code you have there.

Comment: hm, what is the problem then, why file doesn't get properly rewritten here on my machine? I don't see anything implementation defined? the code should run equivalently on all machines right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading and writing to the same file using fstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545155/reading-and-writing-to-the-same-file-using-fstream)

Comment: I think what's going on is that on my system, once the stream hits the EOF condition, no further calls do anything. You don't handle the EOF condition (reading past the end of the stream) at all.  In your case, the file is 10 characters long, and you're reading it 3 at a time. So the last read tries to read two past the end. Since you don't track this, you write out three characters from your buffer even though there is only one valid character in it.

Comment: @Omnifarious That's why I zerro out the buffer for last block: memset(data,0,BLOCK_SIZE); I think that's OK, not sure.

Comment: @zebanovich - It is OK.

Comment: You just need to do a `seekg` before reading as stated in the duplicate, works for me in visual studio

Comment: @AlanBirtles thank you a lot doing seekg before read and seekp before write did a trick! , your comment deserves to be accepted as answer.

Comment: No, its just a duplicate of the answer in the other question, nothing to be gained by repeating it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not handle the EOF condition well, and leaves the stream in a bad state after trying to read past the end of the file. On my system, this results in all further calls to the stream having no effect.  I bet that isn't the case on your system (which I suspect is a bug in its `iostream` implementation). I re-did your code to handle the EOF condition correctly, and also to be a lot cleaner in a few other ways:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int BLOCK_SIZE = 3;

int main()
{
    // open file
    fstream file;
    file.open("sample.txt", ios::binary | ios::out | ios::in);


    // we will read data here
    bool found_eof = false;

    // read blocks of data and write data back
    while (!found_eof)
    {
        unsigned char data[BLOCK_SIZE] = {0};
        char * const data_as_char = reinterpret_cast<char *>(data);
        streampos const pos = file.tellp();
        int count_to_write = BLOCK_SIZE;
        cout << "before read:\t" << file.tellg() << ' ' << pos << '\n';

        // read block
        if (!file.read(data_as_char, BLOCK_SIZE)) {
           found_eof = true;
           count_to_write = file.gcount();
           file.clear();
           cout << "Only " << count_to_write << " characters extracted.\n";
        }
        cout << "after read:\t" << file.tellg() << ' ' << file.tellp() << '\n';

        // write same block back to same position
        file.seekp(pos);
        cout << "before write:\t" << file.tellg() << ' ' << file.tellp() << '\n';
        file.write(data_as_char, count_to_write);
        cout << "after write:\t" << file.tellg() << ' ' << file.tellp() << '\n';
        file.seekp(file.tellp());
    }

    file.close();

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

But, this is not fundamentally different.  Both versions work for me just the same.  I'm on Linux with g++.

From the linked to possible dupe, I would also suggest adding this just before the closing `}` of your `for` loop:

```
file.seekp(file.tellp());
```

I've put that in my code in the appropriate place.

Comment: I copied your code and it results in infinite loop.

Comment: @zebanovich - It works fine on my system. It sounds like you might have a buggy `iostream` implementation. Which compiler and which platform?

Comment: This is really puzzling, Windows 10 x64, msvc-v142 (VS 2019 Preview)

Comment: why casting - reinterpret_cast<char *> required ? VS2019 suggesting to use just (char*)